# How to delay in Subscribe function

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives, angular2-components

**Introduction:** I am trying to build a login page in Angular2 using webapi. My end goal is to redirect the user to a new component on successful login.

**Issue:** My issue is that I am not getting correct result on my first web api hit. I check my web API using postman and it is working fine so the issue is somewhere in the angular code. I research to find out the issue and come uo on conclusion to delay my subscription but not able to delay in my scenario.

Please find the below code:

**Login.component.ts:**

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from './Login.Service';

@Component(
    {
        selector: 'Login',
        templateUrl: './Login.component.html',
    }
)

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    userName: string ;
    paswword: string;
    result: string = 'False';    

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    private myFunc(): void {   
        this.loginService.isLogin("myServiceURL", "userName", this.userName, "pwd", this.paswword)
                         .subscribe(response => this.result = response.toString());
        if (this.result == "True") {
            console.log(this.result);
            console.log(1);
        }
        else {
            console.log(this.result);
            console.log(0);
        }
    }
}
```

**Login.component.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userName"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="paswword"/>
    <button (click)="myFunc()"></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Login.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    respose: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {        
    }

    isLogin(url: string, key1: string, value1: string, key2: string, value2: string): Observable<string> {       
        return this._http.get(url + "?" + key1 + "=" + value1 + "&" + key2 + "=" + value2)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { LoginComponent } from './LoginComponent/Login.component'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginService } from './LoginComponent/Login.Service'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent ],
    bootstrap: [LoginComponent],
    providers: [LoginService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**LoginWebAPI**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace MOMWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string IsLogin(string userName, string pwd)
        {
            string isLogin = "False";
            UserMaster objUserMaster = new UserMaster();
            MOMEntities momEntity = new MOMEntities();
            objUserMaster = momEntity.UserMasters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName && x.Password == pwd);
            if (objUserMaster != null)
            {
                isLogin = "True";
            }

            return isLogin;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any pre-flight error in network monitor, i think you are facing "CORS" issue, if possible can you please share network monitor in developer-tool.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your Network Tab in Chrome and see if your http call is being made by Browser. If it shows up then click on preview to see the response.
However, this code is completely out of place. 
Also the **myFunc** function inside component should not be private unless you are calling it from another function that is exposed to DOM . It should be inside the subscribe function like below:

```
private myFunc(): void {   
    this.loginService.isLogin("myServiceURL", "userName", this.userName, "pwd", this.paswword)
                     .subscribe((response) => {

                        if (!!response) {
                            this.result = response.toString();
                            console.log(this.result);
                            console.log(1);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(this.result);
                            console.log(0);
                        }
                     });

}
```